# Boolean-Valued Models vs. the Infinite-valued Logic of Lukasiewicz and set theory

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, forcing

Is anyone familiar with an old paper of C.C. Chang entitled "The Axiom of Comprehension in Infinite-Valued Logic" which shows that the Axiom of Comprehension without parameters is consistent in the infinite-valued logic of Lukasiewicz and a newer paper by Richard White ("The Consistency of the Axiom of Comprehension in the Infinite-Valued Predicate Logic of Lukasiewicz") in which he shows that the full Axiom of Comprehension is consistent in the infinite-valued predicate logic of Lukasiewicz? I ask because I am interested if finding out if anyone has found a way construe this infinite-valued predicate logic of Lukasiewicz as a Boolean-valued model (or contrariwise, can the full Axiom of Comprehension be shown to be consistent in some Boolean-valued model)?  If so, please provide for me the reference(s).

Comment: No, as far as I am aware. Some recent papers following this old research line are due to Petr Hájek and Shunsuke Yatabe.

Comment: I may misremember it, but I was under the impression that White’s paper is considered faulty among the fuzzy logic people.

Comment: Emil, I would say you remember "half of the story". It is true that some claims in White paper are indeed false, this is proved in Appendix A of Petr Hájek's paper "On White's Expansion of Lukasiewicz Logic".

Comment: Ah, OK, thanks. Anyway, @Thomas: I’m not sure what do you expect to get. Boolean-valued models are models of classical logic, because Boolean algebras are the equivalent algebraic semantics of classical logic. In order to have a model satisfying only Łukasiewicz logic, it needs to have values in an MV-algebra instead. I didn’t read Chang’s or White’s paper, but I’d be surprised if that’s not what they do.

Comment: I see: Chang indeed constructs a model valued in the standard MV-algebra, but White’s argument is proof-theoretic.

Comment: To Emil Jerabek:  I guess what I expect to get is a return to Naive Set Theory, since in the infinite-valued logic of Lukasiewicz, at least Chang may have correctly proven that the Axiom of Comprehension without parameters is consistent. My understanding of boolean-valued models comes from Timothy Chow's "A Beginner's Guide To Forcing" in which he claims that Boolean-valued Models are a type of 'fuzzy set theory'.  Can't a Boolean-valued model based on a Boolean algebra with an infinite number of elements be construed as an infinite-valued logic? 

Comment: To Emil Jerabek:  Also, I understand one can do Forcing in the infinite-valued predicate logic of Lukasiewicz.  Is that sort of forcing essentially similar to Forcing with Boolean-valued models? 

Comment: Chow’s claim is thoroughly misguided, just forget it. Fuzzy set theory is quite a different thing from forcing. An infinite *Boolean*-valued logic is still exactly the same classical logic as the two-valued one, no matter how large a Boolean algebra you take (which is the reason why forcing in ZFC using Boolean-valued models can work in the first place). The number of truth values as such is mostly irrelevant, what matters is what equations hold in the algebra of truth values. The comprehension axiom is inconsistent with classical logic, hence it cannot hold in any Boolean-valued model.

Comment: Emil: Thanks for the comment. Very helpful.  What I would like to know is how Chow could come to be so misguided.  What was the source of his confusion, in your opinion?  Also, when you say, "the number of truth values as such is mostly irrelevant, what matters most is what equations hold in the algebra of truth values," are you referring to 
taking the quotient M^B/U where U is an ultrafilter to form an actual model(in Chow's case, a model of ZFC)?  Also, can one actually do forcing in the infinite-valued predicate logic of Lukasiewicz?  Thanks for your help.     

Comment: I was not referring to any quotient, but to the fact that the logic of an algebra-valued model is determined by the (quasi-)equational theory of the algebra (at least the propositional logic, it gets more complicated for first-order logic). For example, Boolean algebras satisfy the equation $x\lor- x=1$, which means that any Boolean-valued model satisfies the law of excluded middle $\varphi\lor\neg\varphi$. See http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/consequence-algebraic for a quite thorough explanation of the correspondence (they unfortunately do not treat first-order models). As for forcing, ...

Comment: ... ZFC-style forcing is quite tied to the particular set theory it is done in. There is no correspondingly developed set theory over Łukasiewicz logic, and if you pick such a theory (such as the theory with full comprehension), it is quite unclear whether one can adapt forcing to it. There is some work (Takeuti, Titani) on forcing in a ZFC-like set theory over Gödel–Dummett logic, but that’s in a different ballpark from Łukasiewicz logic (the lack of contraction makes a huge difference).

Comment: Emil: I'm looking at the article "Boolean-valued Model" from Springer's Online Encyclopedia of Mathematics (www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Boolean-valued_model) and found an interesting statement..."If a Boolean algebra B is a two-element algebra (i.e. B={0,1} then the B-model M is the classical two-valued model."  This seems to suggest that if B had an infinite number of elements, then the B-model M would essentially have an infinite-valued logic, which under certain conditions could be the infinite-valued logic of Lukasiewicz? 

Comment: By the way, Chang in his paper had the closed interval [0,1] as the truth-values for the infinite-valued Lukasiewicz logic.  It seems rather telling that the elements of [0,1] can be put in a 1-1 correspondence to a complete Boolean algebra.  